# Enable-SPFeature Not firing event receiver

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have been trying to activate a custom feature with an event receiver by powershell, I am using the following command (I ran powershell as administrator)

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity b6e1ccbb-e448-4aed-a303-1b0b900e3e90 -force -Url  $SubWeb.Url
```

The feature appears to be activated however the event receiver doesn't fire, When I activate it from UI it works perfectly

Comment: How do you know receiver is not executed? When you enable feature using PowerShell, receiver will be executed in `powershell.exe` process, not in `w3wp.exe`. Keep it in mind when you attach debugger to test it.

Comment: @dstarkowski the event receiver fills a certain list with values I checked the list its empty after the command however when I activate it using ui it is filled properly

Answer (score 0):

You might be using variables which are not available/accessible in PowerShell but are available if you activate the feature via web (e.g. SPContext, etc.). The best thing would be to attach the debugger to `powershel.exe` as  dstarkowski suggested and check what's wrong.